# iOS Core animation cancel and restart

Tags: swift, ios, animation

There is a simple movement `CAKeyframeAnimation`,  what needs is that I can cancel and restart the animation freely.

The key point of the following code, is that I use `CATransaction.flush()`

I update to the render tree manually.

> If not, Flush is typically called automatically at the end of the current runloop.
>
> Then the animation of my need behaves weirdly, not as expected.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let red = Red(frame: CGRect(x: 200, y: 200, width: 100, height: 100))
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(red)
    }

    // storyboard , button target action
    @IBAction func startAnima(_ sender: UIButton) {
        red.stopAnima()
        CATransaction.flush()
        red.startAnimating()
    }
}

class Red: UIView{
    var isAnimating = false
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }
    
    public func startAnimating() {
         if isAnimating == false {
             isAnimating = true
             animateForward()
         }
     }
    
     public func stopAnima() {
         if isAnimating{
             isAnimating = false
             stopAnimating()
         }
     }
}

extension UIView{
    func animateForward(){
        let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation()
        animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = true
        animation.keyPath = "position.y"
        animation.values = [0, 40, 40, 0]
        animation.keyTimes = [0, 0.3, 0.7, 1]
        animation.duration = 1
        animation.isAdditive = true
        layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    }
    
    func stopAnimating(){
        layer.removeAllAnimations()
    }
}
```

I have an other stupid method, using two views to simulate the needed animation.

[The two demos are here](https://github.com/ForStackO/test)

The above is in the second release.

The stupid is in the first release.

**I want to know how to improve it**

Comment: Welcome to code review, where we review code that is working as expected to suggest ways to improve that code. Code that is not working as expected is considered off-topic.

Comment: It is really working as expected. Thanks for your tips.  Two working methods. Key point is code explain. And any better idea?

Comment: This is a quote from the question : `Then the animation of my need behaves weirdly, not as expected.`

Comment: Please heed some [Swift Style Guide](https://google.github.io/swift/#vertical-whitespace).

Comment: @pacmaninbw， I have a condition `if not`, that explains why I use `CATransaction.flush()`. Use it , and the inner problem has been solved.

Comment: I have edited `Vertical Whitespace` @greybeard

Comment: Your English is very confusing, I'm not sure what to make of this.

Comment: Hope you can improve my poor English. @Mast

Comment: I can't improve your English if I can't make anything of it. This is beyond me.

Comment: I showed the code. Just review